# Recommendations on a sql comparison (schema & data) tool that supports both Oracle and SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

I'm trying to find a good tool (open source or commercial) for doing comparisons of database instances, for example:

1. Compare 2 database schemas; generate **platform specific** change script (either direction) to bring one into synch with the other
2. Compare data (table contents), generate **platform specific** change script (either direction) to bring one into synch with the other
3. Migrate an entire database schema + data from one platform to another, ie: port an Oracle database to SQL Server (hopefully including support for sequences and identity columns)

For 1 & 2 above, by platform specific I mean the script native to the specific database platform, not, for example, an ODBC equivalent script.

Personally, I am mainly concerned with SQL Server and Oracle support, but MySQL support would be very nice to have as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quest Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-sql-server/) or [Red Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) would be the most likely options.

Comment: I second the red gate product.

Comment: Does the Red Gate product support Oracle?

Comment: I was thinking it did, but reading through the product page again I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: Red Gate does now have Schema and Data comparison tools for Oracle. You can download free, 14 day trials from http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/

Answer (score 2):

I'd give a try to "SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle (SSMA for Oracle)"

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Migration-oracle.aspx

It will be really useful to you for points 1 and 3.

I used it with some data migration work, and although it didn't solved everything by itself, it really saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to clarify Red Gate's position. Schema Compare for Oracle is now available. For those who have used SQL Compare (for SQL Server), this tool will be very familiar. [MySQL Compare](http://mysql-compare.com/) also exists.

http://www.red-gate.com/Products/schema_compare_for_oracle/index.htm

Comment: Off-topic, but thanks for the link to oracleoverflow.com - didn't know it existed!

Answer (score 0):

ER/Studio , see http://www.embarcadero.com, will do most of what you're looking for, except for the data comparison.  It is pricey however.

Comment: Eembarcadero's Change manager will do all 3.  It does not support MySQL but it may in a future version as some of their other products do.